# Why are residents of particular states barred from being Amazon affiliates?

Tags: united-states, commerce

[Amazon's affiliate operating agreement](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/help/operating/agreement) contains the following clause:

> In addition, if at any time following your enrollment in the Program
>   you become a resident of Arkansas, Louisiana, Maine, Missouri, Rhode
>   Island, or Vermont, you will become ineligible to participate in the
>   Program, and this Operating Agreement will automatically terminate, on
>   the date you establish residency in that state.

Why would they be excluding these particular states from participation?

Answer (score 10):

These states have relevant (offending) sales tax laws. Amazon has no physical presence in Louisiana, but Louisiana recently passed [HB30](http://www.legis.la.gov/legis/BillInfo.aspx?i=228628) which requires businesses with [in-state affiliates](http://www.legis.la.gov/legis/ViewDocument.aspx?d=983906) (p3 line 25) to remit sales tax, by redefining "physical presence" which is a requirement for collecting sales tax ([Quill Corporation v. North Dakota 504 US 298](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supct/html/91-0194.ZO.html)). Similar laws exist in these states.

It does collect sales tax in Kansas, Kentucky, New York, North Dakota and Washington since it has a real physical presence in these states.